# Why doesn't any content show on top of the Google Maps background?

Tags: html, api, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to make a 100% background of a map. I tried placing content on top but it appears to be behind the map? How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

http://infografi.org/test/index.html

Comment: Please, don't just post a link to your website and hope that we will find what's wrong. Put a bit of effort in so that we will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#wb_Image1` should have its `z-index` set to 1.

[Here is a link to better understand `z-index`.](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)